# How can I get the cell selected in a Vuetify Datatable?

Tags: vuetify.js, vue-cli

I know that I can get the row selected using the event "click:row" in my Datatable component, but I need to get the specific cell that I had clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can use slots for that. Add it inside of your table component like given below:

```
<template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
  <div @click="rowClicked(item)">

    <v-icon  
        class="mr-2"   
        color="#54a1e0"
        large
      >{{ "mdi-folder" }}
    </v-icon>

    {{ item.name }}

  </div>
</template>
```

Here, you call a "rowClicked" method and you pass the clicked item when there is a click on "name" field that you also customise within the template.